# KendoGrid DetailInit not firing when parent grid is refreshed with new data

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a KendoGrid that has a detailInit (hierichal grid)...The master grid contains Group Names, and the child grid contains Options, that is shown on the KendoGrid's detailInit function. This is the flow of steps..

1) Master grid populates when the page is loaded

```
function TheCatalogGrid(catalogData) {
    $("#CatalogGrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            data: catalogData
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "globalGroupID",
            }
        },

        columns: [
           { field: "globalGroupLevel", title: "globalGroupLevel", hidden: true },
           { field: "globalGroupName", title: "Group Name", width:350 },
           { field: "isRequired", title: "*", width:20 },
           { field: "optionName", title: "Option Name" },
           { title: "Description" },
           { title: "Price" }
        ],

        change: function (e) {
            onSelectedRowClick();
        },
        scrollable: true,
        pageable: false,
        selectable: "row",
        height: 500,
        dataBound: function (e) {
            var data = this.dataSource.data();
            $.each(data, function (i, row) {
                if (row.get("globalGroupLevel") == 0) {
                    var element = $('tr[data-uid="' + row.uid + '"] ');
                    element.addClass("colored-row");
                }
            });
        },
        detailInit: detailInit,
        detailExpand: function(e){
            groupID = this.dataItem(e.masterRow).get("globalGroupID");
        },
    });
}
```

2) User clicks the detailExpand on a row and passes that rows group id to

3) The row expands and the child grid populates based on the id that is passed from the maser grids row

```
function detailInit(e) {
    // Added 1/22/2016
    var masterRow = e.masterRow;
    var globalID = e.data.globalGroupID;

    $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: URLParams.GetTheGlobalGroupOptions + "?id=" + e.data.globalGroupID
            },
        },
        scrollable: false,
        selectable: "row",
        filter: { field: "globalGroupID", operator: "eq", value: e.data.globalGroupID },
        change: function (e) {

            // get detail row
            var detailRow = this.dataItem(this.select());
            var optionName = detailRow.get("OptionName") // Change this stuff to populate into the correct columns
            var optionID = detailRow.get("OptionID");

            $("#CatalogGrid").getKendoGrid().dataItem(masterRow).set("optionName", optionName);

            ProcessGlobalOption(optionID, globalID);

            ShowAndHideGroups(0);
        },
        columns: [
            { field: "OptionID", title: "Option ID", hidden:true },
            { field: "OptionName", title: "Option Name" },
            { field: "OptionDescription", title: "Description" },
            { field: "OptionPriceComment", title: "Price" }
        ]
    });
}
```

4) User selects Options

5) The expanded row closes and the Option appears in the Master Grids column called Option

After that happens I have a function called "ProcessGlobalOption", it does some calculating, then I have the ShowAndHideGroups function, that looks like this

```
    function ShowAndHideGroups(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: URLParams.ShowAndHideOptions + "?groupID=" + 0,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            TheCatalogGrid(data);
        }
    });
}
```

and it calls this function from the controller

```
public JsonResult ShowHideGroupOptions(int groupID)
    {
        IncreaseObjectsDemand();
        int currentSectionID = 0;
        _GlobalGroupOptions.CalcAvailableOptions(groupID, _VariableSpaces[currentSectionID.ToString()]);
        IList<IGlobalGroupOption> query = (IList<IGlobalGroupOption>)_GlobalGroupOptions.ToList();

        List<GridCatalog2> lst = new List<GridCatalog2>();
        foreach (var ggo in query)
        {
            lst.Add(new GridCatalog2
            {

                globalGroupID = ggo.GlobalGroup.GlobalGroupID,
                globalGroupLevel = ggo.GlobalGroup.Level,
                globalGroupName = ggo.GlobalGroup.GlobalGroupName,
                isRequired = (ggo.GlobalGroup.Required == 0) ? "" : "!",
                optionName = ggo.CurrentGlobalOption == null ? "" : (ggo.IsValid ? ggo.CurrentGlobalOption.OptionName : ""),
                currentOptionID = ggo.CurrentGlobalOption == null ? 0 : ggo.CurrentGlobalOption.OptionID,
                invalidOption = ggo.CurrentGlobalOption == null ? "" : (ggo.IsValid ? "" : ggo.CurrentGlobalOption.OptionName)
            });
        }
        DecreaseObjectsDemand();

        return Json(lst, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This does return data, the groupID is irrelevant to this method, I don't even need to pass one. This data will hide and show groups and options based on the last selected Option.

Now the first time it runs, I can select an Option from any row, however when I go to select the another row the detailInit fires but no data is being displayed in the child grid, which it should because I am rebinding the grid based on the past back data.

Does this make sense to anyone what I am explaining? if not please ask me to clarify anything.

Comment: Tricky... In the second call to detailInit, do the variables masterRow and globalID contain what you expect?

Comment: @Björn, yes. i j ust double and triple checked

Answer (score 0):

I think this is duplicated instances. When you are calling your `TheCatalogGrid()` function you instanciate an kendoGrid probably you have to do something like:

```
var $catalogGridInstance= null;
function TheCatalogGrid(catalogData) {

  if($catalogGridInstance){
    $catalogGridInstance.destroy();
    $("#CatalogGrid").empty();
    $("#CatalogGrid").remove();
  }

  $catalogGridInstance = $("#CatalogGrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
      data: catalogData
    },
    schema: {
      model: {
        id: "globalGroupID",
      }
    },

    columns: [
      { field: "globalGroupLevel", title: "globalGroupLevel", hidden: true },
      { field: "globalGroupName", title: "Group Name", width:350 },
      { field: "isRequired", title: "*", width:20 },
      { field: "optionName", title: "Option Name" },
      { title: "Description" },
      { title: "Price" }
    ],

    change: function (e) {
      onSelectedRowClick();
    },
    scrollable: true,
    pageable: false,
    selectable: "row",
    height: 500,
    dataBound: function (e) {
      var data = this.dataSource.data();
      $.each(data, function (i, row) {
        if (row.get("globalGroupLevel") == 0) {
          var element = $('tr[data-uid="' + row.uid + '"] ');
          element.addClass("colored-row");
        }
      });
    },
    detailInit: detailInit,
    detailExpand: function(e){
      groupID = this.dataItem(e.masterRow).get("globalGroupID");
    },
  }).data("kendoGrid");
}
```

hope this help

Comment: I got an error, the error is
Uncaught TypeError: $catalogGridInstance.destroy is not a function

Comment: Do you declare  `var $catalogGridInstance= null;` outside `TheCatalogGrid()`  function?

Comment: Yes, I made sure of that I put it outside of the  TheCatalogGrid() function

Comment: Try to do `.data("kendoGrid");` like I did in example

Comment: I added that piece that you mentioned, I must have forgotten it. But when I debug in Chrome, the detailInit starts to open but then disappears, but without debugging in Chrome, the detailInit never opens

Comment: your variables   ` masterRow and globalID ; ` have values that you expect ?

Comment: yes they do, I'll always hit this when trying to open the detailInit...groupID = this.dataItem(e.masterRow).get("globalGroupID");, that always gets populated with the correct ID, thats in the detailExpand function

Comment: And the grid is appended ?

Comment: The grid will rebind but the detailInit will never fire, its weird.